# Why does copying a struct from user space fails in an ioctl command?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

I'm developing a device driver and need to make use of IOCTL. Unfortunately I cannot copy a struct from user space. Here is the code (simplified, error handling removed):

**Structure**

```
struct secvault_createoptions {
    int secvaultId;
    long dataSize;
    char key[SECVAULT_KEYSIZE];
};
```

**Application**

```
void createSecvault(int secvaultId)
{
    struct secvault_createoptions creationOptions;
    /* fill with data */
    sendIoctlCommand(SECVAULT_IOCTL_CREATE, &creationOptions);
}

void sendIoctlCommand(int command, void *arg)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int fd, err;

    stream = fopen(SECVAULT_DEV_CONTROL, "r");
    fd = fileno(stream);
    ioctl(fd, command, arg);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

**Kernel Module**

```
int control_device_ioctl(struct inode *node, struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    struct secvault_createoptions creationOptions;
    int returnCode;

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case SECVAULT_IOCTL_CREATE:
            if (copy_from_user(&creationOptions, (void*)arg, sizeof(struct secvault_createoptions)) != sizeof(struct secvault_createoptions))
            {
                /* Always this branch gets executed */
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Copying secure vault creation options from user space failed.\n");
                returnCode = -EFAULT;
                break;
            }
            printk(KERN_ALERT "2 IOCTL create request on control device received: secvaultId = %d, dataSize = %ld.\n",
                creationOptions.secvaultId, creationOptions.dataSize);

            returnCode = createDataDevice(&creationOptions);
            break;
    }
    return returnCode;
}
```

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `copy_from_user` call is wrong. It does not return the amount of bytes copied, but the number of bytes that were not copied. What you want is

```
if (copy_from_user(...) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
```

(You can skip the assignment to `ret` in your snippet.)

Comment: The usual idiom is if (copy_from_user(...)) return -EFAULT;

Answer (score 3):

`copy_from_user()` returns the number of bytes that could *not* be copied.  So you should expect `0` for success, rather than `sizeof(struct secvault_createoptions)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the statement as ,

```
  if (copy_from_user(&creationOptions, (void*)arg, sizeof(struct secvault_createoptions)) != 0)
            {
                /* Always this branch gets executed */
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Copying secure vault creation options from user space failed.\n");
                returnCode = -EFAULT;
                break;
            }
```

Because `copy_from_user` always returns 0 after successful completion.

Please refer [to this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) for more details.